# In Mocha can I assert that a request times out?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing / confirming some DB lock stuff, and I want to stand up a test that'll confirm that the request ("request-promise" library) will hang if I lock the row.

Some ideas that didn't work were

`request(options).catch((response) => {})`

`assert.throws(fn, Error, "timeout")`

I continue to receive this message: `Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Is there a way to assert that this timeout happens?

Comment: I think if we look at the problem with two different and separate timeouts, it'd work out better. (1) test timeout and (2) asserted timeout. The (2) timeout should be a value you define, which determine if a "hang" condition was met. For example, you can say 5s is good enough. Then (1) timeout just needs to be slightly more (e.g. 1s). There should be some timeout mechanism for your DB library (which times out at 5s), which you can now easily assert. Otherwise, use `setTimeout` to manually assert timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a mocha test (or `describe`, `before`, etc.), `this.timeout(msec)` will change how long the test can run for before Mocha will consider the test failed.

Check out the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#timeout) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set a timeout for half the time I expected the timeout to take.

`setTimeout(function(){ done(); })`

Then in my endpoint promise response I had

`done(new Error("Timeout should have happened.");`

That way, if the timeout happens, `done` gets called. If it doesn't happen, then `done` gets called with an error.